# Timeouts between an API and an elasticsearch server every 2 hours

Tags: debian, php, timeout, api, elasticsearch

We are experiencing a weird issue on our servers. (Debian 8.9) We have an API which is a PHP application. It requests an elasticsearch which instance is on a separate server.

Every 2 hours, we are experiencing errors 500, it lasts during 1 or 2 minutes, rarely more:

```
[2017-10-19 20:52:10] +2 hours
[2017-10-19 22:51:59] +2 hours
[2017-10-20 00:52:02] +2 hours
[2017-10-20 02:52:14] +2 hours
[2017-10-20 04:52:28] +2 hours
```

Sometimes it is +4 hours or +6.

Here is the detail of the error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException: 
"Operation timed out"
```

Which is quite clear. The API tries to connect to the elasticsearch instance until it reaches the specified timeout of the http client.

What could cause this? How to debug this kind of issue?

Of course, when checking later all the URLs referrers, everything is OK.

Comment: Have you raised somaxconn for redis? `net.core.somaxconn=512`?

Comment: Is this parameter related to Redis?

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They finally managed to find the issue. And the root cause is totally stupid. If fact a monitoring view of the es cluster sent a lot of queries to es. About 6 times more than the application itself!

[image: es trans log]

As you can see every 2 hours the memory was too high and the server was unavailable several minutes until it clears the memory (garbage collector).

Other parameters were also optimized and/or increased.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise raising the somaxconn parameter in the kernel.

Add to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.core.somaxconn=512
```

And then run:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Also in `/etc/redis.conf` raise `tcp-backlog` as in (or more):

```
tcp-backlog 512
```

From the redis configuration file:

> TCP listen() backlog.
>
> In high requests-per-second environments you need an high backlog in
>   order  to avoid slow clients connections issues. Note that the Linux
>   kernel  will silently truncate it to the value of
>   /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn so  make sure to raise both the value of
>   somaxconn and tcp_max_syn_backlog  in order to get the desired effect.

Comment: Interesting, I will try this. An idea about the recurring 2 hours delay?

Comment: Try it first and see how it goes.